# How to setFormula with a IF condition?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a tool for my company and I want it to create a new sheet and have a list of them in the "main sheet". When the checkbox is checked in a line of the main sheet, I want a cell in the "secondary sheet" to show "Finish", else "not finished".

My problem is : 
the formula isn't applied to the cell correctly.

I tried to avoid " or " in the setFormula function but nothing changed and I still have "ERROR" in the cell

```
function newsheet(){
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
//All lines to create the new sheet
s.getRange('L1').setValue("=IF(MainSheet!H3=TRU;\"FINISH\";\"NOT FINISHED\")");
}

//I also tried the following :

function tests(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var finished = '"FINISHED"';
  var not_finished = '"NOT FINISHED"';
  s.getRange('L1').setFormula('=IF(MainSheet!H3=TRUE;'+finished+';'+not_finished+')');
}
```

I want this line to apply the formula so any checkbox change at any time can modify the cell without a script but for now I have "formula analysis error" in both tests.

[Image shows incoherence between the cell with formula written by script, the copy/paste cell and the copy/paste formula in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmmJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to alternate single and double quotes in order to avoid a confusion with escaping. Also, there is a small typing mistake in your formula: "TRU" instead of "TRUE".

This works:

```
function newsheet(){
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
//All lines to create the new sheet
s.getRange('L1').setValue('=IF(MainSheet!H3=TRUE;"FINISH";"NOT FINISHED")');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer !
But I still have the same error. Another detail : my google sheet is in French, so i've not "IF" but "SI" and TRUE is VRAI etc.. maybe it could come from this diferences ?

Comment: In French the correct formula would be `=SI(MainSheet!H3=VRAI,"FINISH","NOT FINISHED")`. Is you sheet called indeed `Mainsheet` or do you have a french name for it? What exactly is not working? Be aware that your script sets the formula in the active sheet, which is not necessary the secondary sheet, it is better if you use:  `var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetbyName("NAME OF THE SECONDARY SHEET");`

Comment: I'm aware about that, all my sheets are well defined in my script (I sincerely think the script is OK). My main sheet is called "Demandes". I tried to copy/paste the cell 'L1' in 'L2', it didn't work. I also tried to copy/paste the formula (inside the cell 'L1') written by the script in the cell 'L3' and the formula worked properly in that cell. Another detail : the cell Demandes!H3 contains a checkbox. Maybe it's important ?

Comment: Check this image that illustrate my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmmJ.png

Comment: The true/false statement is interpreted correctly for checkboxes. In you snippet it looks like the formula is in quotes? Maybe you can click into cell `L1` and provide a snippet of the value displayed in the formula editor? Otherwise, if you provide a copy of your sheet (please remove personal information) I can have a look at it.

Comment: The script is now woking, you can check my answer to my question. I don't know what happened, a kind of bug maybe ? something wrong between english in script and french in sheets ? Anyway, thank you for your help and the time you spent to explain everything.

Comment: For me `setValue()` also works, so if it does not for you, I assume that it is due to the country settings, in any case glad that it works now!

Answer (score 0):

After several tries I found something:

```
    function tests(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  s.getRange('L1').setFormula("IF(H3=TRUE;\"TERMINEE\";\"EN COURS\")");
}
```

This works but my script was the same yesterday (but in french) and it doesn't understand french anymore.